# Scala-cat's IOApp in an OSGi context

Tags: scala, functional-programming, osgi, scala-cats, io-monad

An application I am currently developing is written in a functional programming style using [scala-cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/)' [IOApp](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/ioapp.html).

Now the problem is that I need to deploy this application in an OSGi context that does not really seem to fit my functional approach.

My main method looks like this:

```scala
object Main extends IOApp {
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = for {
    _ <- IO(println("Starting with args: " + args.mkString(",")))
    myProgram = new MyProgram(/*...*/)
    _ <- myProgram.run() // def run(): IO[RunResult]
    // ...
    _ <- myProgram.exit() // def exit(): IO[Unit]
    } yield ExitCode.Success
}
```

Now to deploy this to OSGi I had to write a [BundleActivator](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html):

```scala
import org.osgi.framework.{BundleActivator, BundleContext}

class Activator extends BundleActivator {

  private var myProgram: Option[myProgram] = None

  override def start(context: BundleContext): Unit = {
    myProgram = Some(new MyProgram(/*...*/))
    myProgram.foreach{ _.run().unsafeRunSync() }
  }

  override def stop(context: BundleContext): Unit = {
    myProgram.foreach{ _.exit().unsafeRunSync() }
  }
}
```

As you can see this `Activator` I came up with is far from being written in a functional manner. Is there any way I can at least get rid of `var myProgram` (the mutable `var` to be specific)? I can't seem to figure out how that would be possible.

**Edit:**
The activator needs to be defined in the manifest, so this is part of my `build.sbt`:

```scala
packageOptions := Seq(ManifestAttributes(
  ("Bundle-Activator", "my.package.Activator"),
  ...))
```

Comment: Consider making a custom `cats.effect.Resource` to represent BundleActivator`

Comment: Also, I still see to reason why you are using `var` and `Option`. `IO` is lazy.

Comment: @V-Lamp What you're saying doesn't really make sense. You're going to have to point to the activator in the manifest, so where does `Resource` come in? How does the laziness of `IO` have anything to do with the use of `var` or `Option` here?

Comment: My comments were before the edits showing `packageOptions`, I see now it doesn't make sense :)

Comment: Why do you feel your bundle needs to have a Bundle-Activator?

Comment: Well it needs to be able to start and stop as a bundle in an OSGi context.

Comment: Okay, first of all does `myProgram` have type `Option`? The stop method *cannot* be called unless the start method was previously called, so you can safely assume the `myProgram` field is non-null in the stop method. Also why is it necessary to call `unsafeRunSync` in the OSGi example but not in the non-OSGi example? I know very little Scala and I've never heard of scala-cats but this change doesn't seem to be driven by OSGi.

Comment: My question is probably hard to answer without knowledge of scala-cats. From the limited knowledge I have: `IOApp` gives the user an entry point to a 'pure' FP program. It actually calls `unsafeRunSync` invisible to the programmer, that's why the return type is an IO monad. Since the `BundleActivator`'s `stop` and `start` methods do not follow this paradigm, I have to manually run my program using `unsafeRunSync`. I don't think I can change this fact, but I wanted to have some input on how I can better work around these limitations imposed on me by OSGi.

Comment: Just to clarify: **The code above works perfectly well!** It's just not 'pure'/FP enough in my opinion.

Comment: As for why `myProgram` is an Option: I don't want to - ever - assign `null` to a variable. ;)

Comment: You never will assign null to a variable. That was the point I was making.

Comment: Regarding the limitations imposed on you, TBH it seems most of these come from scala-cats rather than OSGi. In OSGi you only need to respond to a "start" and a "stop" callback by implementing an interface. In scala-cats you have to inherit from a base class, which doesn't sound very functional to me, but what the hell do I know? ;-)

Comment: Hmm, this `run()` method from `IOApp` is used because otherwise, with Scala's default main method, I would have to call `unsafeRunSync`. I am not trying to criticize how OSGi works, just trying to figure out how to best fit this into a pure FP application.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to avoid some nasty Java-esque code here, this is just how OSGi works. But what you can do is hide the nastiness in a reusable class, so you only need to get it right once and never look at it again. My suggestion would be a generic Activator that will acquire a cats `Resource` on startup and dispose of it it when you shut it down.

```scala
class ResourceActivator(resource: BundleContext => Resource[IO, Unit])
  extends BundleActivator {

  private var cleanup: IO[Unit] = null

  override def start(context: BundleContext): Unit =
    cleanup = resource(context).allocate.unsafeRunSync()._2

  override def stop(context: BundleContext): Unit =
    cleanup.unsafeRunSync()
}
```

Valid OSGi implementations will never call `stop` without calling `start` first, so it's OK to initialize `cleanup` to `null`.

Note that the above class easily allows you to e. g. start some asychronous computation in the `start` method and shut it down in the `stop` method:

```scala
class MyActivator extends ResourceActivator(ctx =>
  for {
    res1 <- someResource
    res2 <- anotherResource
    _ <- Resource.make(doSomeStuff.start)(_.cancel)
  } yield ()
)
```